# Adding duplicates to SailsJS model with many-to-many association

Tags: javascript, many-to-many, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have two models, items and order, that have a many-to-many association.  What I've been trying to do for the past 5 hours is figure out a way to add multiple items objects to an order including duplicates.

If the items are unique it works perfectly fine, but if I try something like this:

```
    order.items.add([12, 13, 12, 12]);
    order.save();
```

It will only save 12, 13.  The duplicates will be ignored, not so good if you want to order more than one of any item.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Many-to-many association in DB scheme is creating relation between any record from a table to any record to another table, of course it always unique, because `12` is already has an association with that `order` record.

The solution is, use extra model to achieve that. For example, in `models` folder:

#### Order.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    items : {collection: 'OrderItem', via: 'order'}
  }
};
```

#### OrderItem.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    order : {model: 'Order'},
    item  : {model: 'Item'}
  }
};
```

#### Item.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
  }
};
```

So from `Order` model, you can add some `OrderItem` that is a model that represent relation between `Order` and `Item`, and `OrderItem` is unique in `Order` point of view though an Item under it's record may be same.

Comment: Yep good point but I was trying to avoid doing that because sails creates a join table automagically.  I know if I look at my staging that's using MySQL it does have the OrderItems table created by Sails to handle this.  Turns out the Sails-disk db that it ships with has this issue but if I use my Mongo or MySQL connections it works like a charm.

Comment: But the problem is, it can't rely on basic/ standard many-to-many DB association, as I mention that `12` is already has an association with `order` that you mentioned. It needs a `something in between` to be a bridge between `Order` and `Item` that can represent a unique value from `Order` point of view.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go with creating a new model for maintaining the many-to-many association but another way would be adding a column in your Order model called "Quantity" and increment it whenever you're adding the same item again.